# Angular 5 Routing - Header and Navigation Bar Routing Issue

Tags: angular, angular5

I need to display 3 components (Header, Navigation Bar and Menu items) in my Angular 5 application. I am new to Angular and worked like below -

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavigationBarComponent } from './navigation-bar/navigation-bar.component';
import { SendPaymentsComponent } from './send-payments/send-payments.component';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TopHeaderComponent } from './top-header/top-header.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
path: '',
component: NavigationBarComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'send-payments',
    component: SendPaymentsComponent
  }
]
 }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavigationBarComponent,
    SendPaymentsComponent,
    TopHeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-top-header></app-top-header>
<app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Assume that `navigation-bar.component.html`  has html code to display a navigation bar with some menu item (payments). 'send-payments.component.html' has data to display payments.

On accessing 'localhost:4200', I wanted to display both top-header and navigation-bar components. I am not getting where to add top-header component in `app.module.ts` and `app.component.html`

Adding  in app.component.html displaying same html of navigation bar twice.

Comment: What happen if you remove `app-navigation-bar` from `app.component.html`?

Comment: I got the same doubt and removing it did eliminated the issue of double display of nav bar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution

I have create a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-routing-header-and-navigation-bar-routing-issue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

> ts file code

```
const app_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/payment',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }, {
    path: 'payment',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/send-payments',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'send-payments',
        component: SendPaymentComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'get-payments',
        component: GetpaymentComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'others',
        component: OtherComponent
      },

    ]
  }
];
```